# For loop range in Bash

Tags: bash

Im trying a code in bash to generate prime nos as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Enter till where u wish to generate"
read num
echo "Generating prime numbers from 2 to $num"

flag="prime"

for i in {2..$num}
do

for j in {2..$((${num}-1))}
 do

 [ $((${i}%${j})) -eq 0 ] && flag="nprime" || flag="prime"
 break
 done

 [ "$flag" == "prime" ] && echo "$i"

done
```

Upon execution, it throws an error because the for loop takes the sequence mentioned in the curly braces as it is not as a sequence.
Could you guide me as to where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man bash` in my version says:

> A  sequence  expression  takes  the  form  `{x..y[..incr]}`,  where  `x` and `y` are either integers or single characters, and `incr`, an optional increment, is an integer.

You can't use variables in ranges. Try `seq` instead:

```
for i in $(seq 2 $num) ; do
```

Note that `incr` for `seq` goes between `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank you! 
seq seems to be a better approach!

Comment: The reason is the order of [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) -- brace expansion occurs before parameter expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
for ((i=2; i<=$num; i++))
```